# Usar SVG como Background-Image

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

Tengo un proyecto donde se me da un .svg para usar de `background-image` en un proyecto React.
No sé si hay alguna manera de referenciarlo en la propiedad `backgroundImage` si lo convierto en un componente, o algo asi.

Mi idea seria una cosa asi:

```
 <div
  className={cssClasses}
   style={{
      backgroundImage: `url((acá el svg de alguna manera potable))`,
    }}
      >
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿La imágen esta disponible en alguna carpeta del directorio de la `app`?, saludos

Answer (score 2):

Se puede usar concatenación de `strings` ES5:

```
style={{backgroundImage:"url(" + imagen + "})"
```

O se puede usar ES6 [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
style={{backgroundImage:`url(${imagen})`
```

Demo Template Literals:

```js
const imagen = " https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/99/Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg/800px-Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg.png"

function App() {
  return (
        <div style={{backgroundImage:`url(${imagen})`,
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        width:300,
        height:300}}></div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución seria utilizar el svg como data URI algo así:

Por favor observa que -a pesar de los cambios- el svg queda humanamente legible.

```css
#svgbg{
height:200px;
width:200px; 
border:1px solid;
background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200' viewBox='0 0 26 26'%3E%0A%3Cpath d='M5,7a2,2 0 1 1 2,-2a2,2 0 0 0 4,0a2,2 0 0 1 4,0a2,2 0 0 0 4,0a2,2 0 1 1 2,2a2,2 0 0 0 0,4a2,2 0 0 1 0,4a2,2 0 0 0 0,4a2,2 0 1 1 -2,2a2,2 0 0 0 -4,0a2,2 0 0 1 -4,0a2,2 0 0 0 -4,0a2,2 0 1 1 -2,-2a2,2 0 0 0 0,-4a2,2 0 0 1 0,-4a2,2 0 0 0 0,-4z' fill='pink' stroke='black'%3E%3C/path%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}
```

```html
<div id="svgbg"></div>
```

Por favor observa que:

`<` se transforma en `%3C`
`>` se transforma en `%3E`

Por ejemplo  vuelve a ser %3Csvg%3E

`#` se transforma en `%23`

Por ejemplo fill = "#abcdef" vuelve a ser fill = "%23abcdef"

el guión `-` se transforma en `%2D`

Por ejemplo stroke-width="2" vuelve a ser stroke%2Dwidth="2"

el símbolo matemático porcien `%` se transforma en `%25`

Por ejemplo width ='50%' vuelve a ser width ='50%25'

Puedes utilizar este [URL-encoder for SVG](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs) o puedes [leer como hacerlo aquí](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/svg/utilizar-svg.php#data_uri).